# Disable database migrations in Sails.js for all models

Tags: sails.js

I'm trying to figure out how to disable automatic database migrations for Models in Sails.js.

I know you can set `migrate: 'safe'` in the model, but is there a way to specify this for all models?

Comment: Hi Shaheen, there's not a way to do this right now, but I would suggest adding a feature request for this here: https://trello.com/b/cGzNVE0b/sails-js-feature-requests

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Actually, there is a way to do it. ORM hooks [are getting defaults from `sails.config.model`](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/blob/9c751663ab29b8b2c4e21dce936f014018bacbaf/lib/hooks/orm/index.js#L73), so all you have to do is to create `config/model.js` with the following content:

```
module.exports.model = {
  migrate: 'safe'
}
```

After this the migrations won't be running upon `sails lift`, but they will still be applied once you create a document, for example.

Comment: Can we use `migrate` setting on per-model basis?

Comment: @sasha.sochka yeah, if you follow the link in the answer, you'll see that model properties override the defaults, so using `migrate` on per-model basis should work perfectly.