# sails-mongo throwing error on 0.10.2

Tags: sails.js, waterline, sails-mongo

I'm trying to use waterline 0.10 with sails-mongo outside sails and everything is working fine  but when I upgraded sails-mongo from 0.10.0-rc5 to 0.10.2 I'm getting now an error below is the error I getting.

`Waterline encountered a fatal error when trying to perform the`alter`auto-migration strategy.`

...

`Error (E_UNKNOWN) :: Encountered an unexpected error: Message contains no documents`

...

`Details:  MongoError: Message contains no documents`

Thanks in advance guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sails-mongo 0.10.1 seems not affected.

The 0.10.2 release also seems to remove attributes on documents: https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-mongo/issues/174

This auto-migration behaviour is not enabled on production environments, and you can force it disabled as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21072898/disable-database-migrations-in-sails-js-for-all-models).

Comment: Thanks, I also updated my sails-mongo and i got 0.10.3 and everything working now.

Answer (score 0):

Yes downgrade to 0.10.1, the migration-function is disabled there.